# Son secretly records family for internet show

Tags: identify-this-movie

I am stuck trying to find this movie, here is what I remember of it:

Basically, there is a family, the son in the family for whatever reason secretly sets up hidden cameras all around the house, and decides to start streaming it on the internet as a commercial show. It becomes big, and people start recognizing the family members in the streets, etc., but of course, they are completely oblivious as to why or what is going on.
Eventually, the truth comes out, but I believe due to financial issues the family decides to willingly participate in continuing the internet show. Eventually it all ends with the father going mad and blowing up the house live with a gasoline canister.

Can anyone please tell me what the title of this movie was, or any information that may help me find it?

Comment: I might have seen this but i also doesn't remember the name or any other detail.

Comment: When did you watch it? When do you think it was made? Was it in English? Hollywood? How many members do you remember being in the family? More information please.

Comment: I think I watched it in 2007/8, or thereabouts. It was made sometime between 1996-2007/8. It was an English, American-made movie, so yes I believe it is a Hollywood movie.
As far as I can remember, there were only 4 members of the family, son/daughter/father/mother, but I am only basing that off the fact that I do not remember any other characters.

Comment: It cannot be too far in the past. Streaming live videos over Internet is a recent thing. Back in 1996, this technology wasn't so easy to setup, specially that was the age of dial-up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of [I-See-You.Com](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0489085/).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-See-You.Com):

> Harvey Bellinger (Beau Bridges), his wife Lydia (Rosanna Arquette), and their two teenage kids live a well-to-do life in suburbia. This changes, however, when their seventeen-year-old son puts video cameras around their house, and starts to broadcast the family's actions live on the internet. When Harvey finds about this, he is angry and appalled.